# Django select_related() with latest() limit on related object

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Consider having `Table` table and `Reservation` table in my restaurant Django APP.

```
class Reservation(models.Model):

    table = models.ForeignKey(
        Table,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,null=False,
        related_name='reservations'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)

class Table(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

If I wanna to show a list of restaurant tables with it's corresponding reservation, then I need to select related reservation for each table. but I need to select related only the last reservation of each table (that is active right now).

> How To Achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `prefetch_related()` not `select_related()` because of the **oneToMany** reverse relation,

Secondly you could simply use the orm `tableObject.reservations.last()` or `tableObject.reservations.latest('created_at')`